# unresponsive error in calling Api the movie Database in ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, fragment, retrofit

I am trying to work with retrofit and viewmodel architecture, however I am not able to execute the call from Api the movie Database

In the project, in the creation of my fragment adds the call of the getPopularMovies () method of the ViewModel which is responsible for making the call to the interface where it contains the @GET method for API. But the retries exactly return onError in the RepositoryImpl and in the ViewModel

```
interface TMDbService{

    @GET("movie/popular")
    fun getPopuparMovies(@Query("api_key") apiKey: String,
                         @Query("language") lang: String,
                         @Query("page") page: Int): Call<MovieResponse>

}

interface OnGetMoviesCallback{
    fun onSuccess(movies: List<Movie>)
    fun onError()
}
```

RepositoryImpl

```
open class MovieRepositoryImpl: MovieRepository {
    private var service: TMDbService

    companion object {
        const val BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/"
        const val LANGUAGE = "pt-BR"
        const val API_KEY = "XXX"
        const val DEFAULT_PAGE_VALUE = 1
    }

    init {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        service = retrofit.create(TMDbService::class.java)
    }

    override fun getPopularMovies(callback: OnGetMoviesCallback) {
        service.getPopuparMovies(API_KEY, LANGUAGE, DEFAULT_PAGE_VALUE)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<MovieResponse>{
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<MovieResponse>, response: Response<MovieResponse>) {

                    if (response.isSuccessful){
                        val movieResponse = response.body()
                        if (movieResponse?.movies != null){
                            callback.onSuccess(movieResponse.movies)
                        } else {
                            callback.onError()
                            Log.e("Response", javaClass.simpleName + " response null")
                        }
                    } else {
                        callback.onError()
                        Log.e("Response", javaClass.simpleName + " not response 1")
                    }

                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<MovieResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    callback.onError()
                    Log.e("Response", javaClass.simpleName + " not response 2")
                }
            })
    }

}
```

ViewModel.kt

```
class HomeViewModel(private val repository: MovieRepository = MovieRepositoryImpl()) : ViewModel() {

    fun verifyConnectivity(activity: HomeActivity): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected
    }

    fun getPopularMovies(){

        repository.getPopularMovies(object : OnGetMoviesCallback{
            override fun onSuccess(movies: List<Movie>) {
                Log.d("OnSuccess", "Its Ok")
            }

            override fun onError() {
                Log.e("ErrorViewModel", "Error in viewmodel call")
            }
        })

    }

}
```

Models

```
data class Movie(
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    val id: Int = 0,

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    val title: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    @Expose
    val posterPath: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("release_date")
    @Expose
    val releaseDate: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    @Expose
    val rating: Float = 0.toFloat(),

    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    @Expose
    val genreIds: List<Int>? = null,

    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    @Expose
    val backdropPath: String? = null)

data class MovieResponse(
    @SerializedName("page")
    @Expose
    val page: Int = 0,

    @SerializedName("total_results")
    @Expose
    val totalResults: Int = 0,

    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    val movies: List<Movie>? = null,

    @SerializedName("total_pages")
    @Expose
    val totalPages: Int = 0
)
```

In this case the start of the call is in the ViewModel in the getPopularMovies () method, which when called returns in the error log the logs with the descriptions: "not response 2" in the repository and "Error in viewmodel call" in ViewModel.
What I hope is that my service at the end can CALL this URL: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=XXX&language=en&page=1

with the equal return Json below:

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "total_results": 19779,
    "total_pages": 989,
    "results": [
        {
            "vote_count": 1267,
            "id": 166428,
            "video": false,
            "vote_average": 7.7,
            "title": "Como Treinar o Seu Dragão 3",
            "popularity": 493.655,
            "poster_path": "/5uqxMHM7YLKk6yni4bOE0D6DVz8.jpg",
            "original_language": "en",
            "original_title": "How to Train Your Dragon: The Hidden World",
            "genre_ids": [
                16,
                10751,
                12
            ],
            "backdrop_path": "/h3KN24PrOheHVYs9ypuOIdFBEpX.jpg",
            "adult": false,
            "overview": "Soluço busca realizar seu grande sonho de encontrar um lar pacífico onde os dragões possam viver em segurança. Lá, Banguela descobre uma companheira, assim como ele, mas um tanto selvagem. Mas é quando o perigo começa a rondar o lar, que a dupla Banguela e Soluço é testada e precisa tomar decisões difíceis para salvar suas espécies.",
            "release_date": "2019-01-03"
        },
        {
            "vote_count": 3316,
            "id": 299537,
            "video": false,
            "vote_average": 7.2,
            "title": "Capitã Marvel",
            "popularity": 369.741,
            "poster_path": "/hVgLHgnsO46oSHJy5I4ekhqtoYv.jpg",
            "original_language": "en",
            "original_title": "Captain Marvel",
            "genre_ids": [
                28,
                12,
                878
            ],
            "backdrop_path": "/w2PMyoyLU22YvrGK3smVM9fW1jj.jpg",
            "adult": false,
            "overview": "A história segue Carol Danvers e como ela se torna um dos heróis mais poderosos do universo quando a Terra é pega no meio de uma guerra galáctica entre duas raças alienígenas. Situado na década de 1990, Capitã Marvel é uma nova aventura de um período inédito na história do universo cinematográfico da Marvel.",
            "release_date": "2019-03-06"
        },
        {
            "vote_count": 632,
            "id": 458723,
            "video": false,
            "vote_average": 7.4,
            "title": "Nós",
            "popularity": 185.833,
            "poster_path": "/ioceyCFcOC9LfUCkOGZNMbsuc2o.jpg",
            "original_language": "en",
            "original_title": "Us",
            "genre_ids": [
                53,
                27
            ],
            "backdrop_path": "/ADJ6V8W96It4KElY2SPZvkKPBR.jpg",
            "adult": false,
            "overview": "O casal Gabe e Adelaide Wilson leva seus filhos para uma casa de praia, esperando se desconectar e descontrair com os amigos. Mas à medida que a noite cai, sua serenidade se transforma em tensão e caos quando alguns visitantes chocantes chegam sem serem convidados.",
            "release_date": "2019-03-14"
        },
```

Log Error printStackTrace()

```java
W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb93b5090: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:281)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:251)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:151)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:192)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: can you show the error log

Comment: you can log error by `t.printStackTrace()`  (t here is your Throwable)
```then run code again and check logcat

Comment: With t.printStackTrace(): W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb93b5090: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)

Comment: can you try to call this API by your browser, it work or not

Comment: yes, it is, I am using postman for this and the return is coming as expected.

Comment: same wifi right? your post man have not ignore SSH (in setting)? your browser (chrome, ...) call success?

Comment: Yes, in my browser and Postman the call occurs successfully and Json is returned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191288/discussion-between-phan-van-linh-and-eduardo-rafael-moraes).